# Can't connect to my SQL Server Express from an ASP.NET web app

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, azure, sql-server-express

I'm working on a tool that uses an SQL Server as a database.

First I was using Visual Studio's localdb, then I was using an Azure SQL Server, both of which worked just fine.

I now tried to host my own SQL Server Express, but I can't seem to connect to it. It's hosted in an Azure VM, I have restarted it, enabled TCP and I have opened Port 1433 in Azure.

I have tried both connecting remotely, running the web-app on my local computer and connecting to `tcp:{IP}\InstanceName`, as well as running the app on an IIS Server on my VM using `.\InstanceName` in the connection string (although I still get told to check if the server is set up correctly to handle TCP ? )

Connecting locally on the VM, using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio works though, so I suspect the connection string in my `web.config` must be wrong ...

It looks like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="defaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Server=tcp:12.345.678.910\InstanceName,1433;Initial Catalog=master;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Password={mypassword};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The error message I get is:

> Server Error in '/application-name' Application. The remote computer refused the network connection.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The remote computer refused the network connection
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace: [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The remote computer refused
>   the network connection]
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The remote computer refused the network connection.)]

*(and more but it doesn't seem important - will post if necessary or helpful)*

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You had better check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-sql-connect) firstly.

Comment: You tell me: https://imgur.com/a/yJjJw .

And Windows Firewall has been both disabled (for testing) as well as configured to open port 1433 for TCP

Comment: I think I did everything that is described in that link although my VM Blade in the portal looks different - there is no SQL Server tab. That's because I didn't set it up in Azure though, I just manually installed SQL Server Express in the operating system.

Comment: Could you `telnet <publicip> 1433`? What is the result `netstat -ant|findstr 1433`?

Comment: `Connecting locally on the VM, using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio works though` You use `public IP` on SSMS?

Comment: telnet tells me I can't connect ... so a firewall issue after all, I don't get it ...

Comment: No, I use servername\InstanceID

Comment: On SSMS you could try to use Public IP, if you could connect it, it seems a firewall issue.

Comment: It's a ARM VM I believe although I am not a 100% sure. (I wasn't the one who set it up originally). It doesn't appear if I filter for Classic machines though.

Comment: SSMS connection to public IP doesn't work either, same error message :/ Guess I have some sifting through settings to do . Thanks a lot for the help !

Comment: Could you share your VM screenshot? Remove sensitive information.

Comment: Sorry, going to have to do that later, can't login into my account due to an unrelated issue right now. Thanks for the offer though, maybe I'm lucky and you or someone else will see it later !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution on my own:

It's not enough to enable TCP in the Server Configuration Manager, you also have to SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for X > TCP > Properties > IP Adresses and set TCP Port to 1433 under IPAll.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server **Express** doesn't allow remote connections - by default.

You need to **explicitly enable** remote connections - easiest way is to use SQL Server Management Studio, connect to it, and then in "Object Explorer" right-click on the server icon, and pick "Properties".

In the dialog that shows up, make sure to **tick** the "Allow remote connections to this server" checkbox:

[image]